# How can I set/get form data in Fancybox pop-up window using content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox2 and I have a problem.
I can't figure out how to set/get form-data in Fancybox pop-up window.

What I want to do is:

1. The value of `textarea` (`#edit_BM1`) should be set using the value of
   hidden tag(`#BM1`) when I `click` the *table cell*(`.cli_BM1`) and popup window
   should be shown.
2. Popup window should be closed when I `click` *Cancel* button.
3. Or the value of hidden tag(`#BM1`) should be set using the value of
   `textarea` (`#edit_BM1`) when I `click` *Update* button.

Actually,

1. Popup window showed but the value of `textarea` (`#edit_BM1`) didn't
   change.
2. Nothing happened when I `click` *Cancel* or *Update* button.

Here in my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(function () {
    $(".cli_BM1").click(function () {
        $("#edit_BM1").val($("#BM1").val());
        $.fancybox({
            "content" : $("#BM1").html()
        });
    });
    $(".btn_cancel").click(function () {
        $.fancybox.close();
    });
    $("#btn_BM1").click(function () {
        $("#BM1").val($("#edit_BM1").val());
        $.fancybox.close();
    });
});
-->
</script>
```

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="cli_BM1" id="c_BM1"></td>
    <td class="cli_BM2" id="c_BM2"></td>
    <td class="cli_BM3" id="c_BM3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="BM1" id="BM1" value="" />
<div id="BM1" style="display:none">
    <textarea name="edit_BM1" id="edit_BM1" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="popup_btn_area">
    <button class="btn_cancel">Cancel</button>
    <button id="btn_BM1">Update</button>
</div>
</div><!-- /BM1 -->
```

How can I specify the selector in the popup window?
Please tell me the right way if you have any idea.

Thank you.

11/25/2014 added:

Here is the demo page:

http://awawa.jp/demo/141125/index.html

Click 6 cells to show popup windows.

> Popup window showed but the value of `textarea` (`#edit_BM1`) didn't change.

Solved. I wrote a wrong code. `.text()` should be used instead of `.val()`.

index.html

- Line 56-64: `.prop()` and `.val()` don't work.
- Line 124-127: this event doesn't fire by clicking `button.btn_cancel`.

I really appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: Don't you have a stray `</div>`? ... what version of fancybox?

Comment: Also you have two elements sharing the same `#BM1` ID selector : the `input` and the hidden `div`, which apart from being invalid it might be creating issues while manipulating DOM elements

Comment: I use juery-1.8.3 and Fancybox-2.1.4. Sorry, I posted a wrong code. Id of the hidden tag is really "BM1-1" etc. and not the same.